# prototype.js highlight words. DOM traversing correctly and efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, highlight

I want to highlight a specific word in my HTML page after the page is loaded. I don't want to use the dumb:

```
document.innerHTML = document.innerHTML.replace(.....);
```

I want to traverse every DOM node, find out the ones that contain text and modify the innerHTML of only those individual nodes. Here's what I came up with:

```
function highlightSearchTerms(sword) {
$$('body').map(Element.extend).first().descendants().each(function (el) {
    if (el.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && el.tagName != 'TD') {
        //$A(el.childNodes).each(function (onlyChild) {
            //if (onlyChild.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                //console.log(onlyChild);
                el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('('+sword+')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
            //}
        //});
    }
});
//document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('('+sword+')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
}
```

It works as it is right now, but it's VERY inefficient and is hardly better than the single line above as it may do a replacement several times over the same text. (Hmmm..., or not?)

If you uncomment the commented stuff and change `el.innerHTML.replace` to `onlyChild.textContent.replace` it would work almost like it needs to, but modifying textContent doesn't create a new span as an element, but rather adds the HTML content as text.

My question/request is to find a way that it highlights the words in the document traversing elements one by one.

Answer (score 1):

This works quick and clean:

```
function highlightSearchTerms(sword) {
$$('body').map(Element.extend).first().descendants().each(function (el) {
    if (el.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && el.tagName != 'TEXTAREA' && el.tagName != 'INPUT' && el.tagName != 'SCRIPT') {
        $A(el.childNodes).each(function (onlyChild) {
            var pos = onlyChild.textContent.indexOf(sword);
            if (onlyChild.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && pos >= 0) {
                //console.log(onlyChild);
                var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                spannode.className = 'highlight';
                var middlebit = onlyChild.splitText(pos);
                var endbit = middlebit.splitText(sword.length);
                var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);

                //onlyChild. = el.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('('+sword+')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

But I've trouble understanding how exactly it works. This seems to be the magic line:

```
middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
```

Comment: yay for prototype port of the jquery one i posted :) I'm going to go ahead and steal this for my own site.

Answer (score 1):

I converted one from jQuery to PrototypeJS some time ago :

```
Element.addMethods({
  highlight: function(element, term, className) {
    function innerHighlight(element, term, className) {
      className = className || 'highlight';
      term = (term || '').toUpperCase();

      var skip = 0;
      if ($(element).nodeType == 3) {
        var pos = element.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(term);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var middlebit = element.splitText(pos),
              endbit = middlebit.splitText(term.length),
              middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true),
              spannode = document.createElement('span');

          spannode.className = 'highlight';
          spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
          middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
          skip = 1;
        }
      }
      else if (element.nodeType == 1 && element.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(element.tagName)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; ++i)
          i += innerHighlight(element.childNodes[i], term);
      }
      return skip;
    }
    innerHighlight(element, term, className);
    return element;
  },
  removeHighlight: function(element, term, className) {
    className = className || 'highlight';
    $(element).select("span."+className).each(function(e) {
      e.parentNode.replaceChild(e.firstChild, e);
    });
    return element;
  }
});
```

You can use it on every element like this:

```
$("someElementId").highlight("foo", "bar");
```

, and use the className of your choice. You can also remove the highlights.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using the **prototype version posted by Fabien**, make sure to add the className
as argument to the call of innerHighlight:

```
i += innerHighlight(element.childNodes[i], term)
```

needs to be

```
i += innerHighlight(element.childNodes[i], term, className)
```

if you care about custom classNames for your highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Grab $(document.body) and do a search/replace and wrap a span around the term, then swap the entire $(document.body) in one go. Treat it as a big string, forget about the DOM. This way you only have to update the DOM once. It should be very quick.

Comment: I think this would cause problems if the word he wanted to highlight happened to be something like: "input" or "span"  or "value, basically anything that could be in the markup as opposed to the displayed text

Comment: That's exactly the situation I've noticed now. No go.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a script that will do what you want (it seems pretty fast),  it is not specific to any library so you may want to modify it:

http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm

The method you provided above (although commented out) will have problems with replacing items that might be inside a  an html element.  ie ` a search and replace might "highlight" "thing" when that would not be what you want.

here is a Jquery based highlight script:

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

It dosent look to hard to convert to prototype.

Comment: I know http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm and used it until today, when I found out it's not working with Ajax somehow. And it's doing the same innerHTML processing - just a bit more fancy.

Comment: I know http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html as well and I've followed your suggestion even before you suggested it. I've got it working based on this jQuery code, but I still don't understand how it works. See my own answer below.